# How Show Success Message After form submit in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

How Show Success Message After form submit in word press ? This code is used for review submission .I need to show success message(Your review has been successfully submitted) after submit my review.My html code :

```
     <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="reviews">
    <?php
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        ?> 
    <h2>REVIEWS ON <?php echo get_the_title(); ?> </h2> 
    <div class="message-box">
     <form method="post">
      <div class="rating">
        <div class="rating-inner">
          <div id="rateYo1"></div><p>Rate the store</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <textarea class="review_message" name="message_review" id="message" placeholder="Type your review here..." required></textarea>
      <button class="review_submit_button" name="review_submit" value="Submit Review">Submit Review</button>
      <input type="hidden" id="data-rating" name="data-rating" >
    </form>
      </div>
      <?php }?> 
    </div>
     </div>
    </div>
<?php 
$img = showImage();
$user_avatar=$img[0]->mem_photo;
if (isset($_POST['review_submit'])) {
    $review_content = $_POST['message_review'];
    $data_rating = $_POST['data-rating'];
    $shop_id = get_the_ID();
    add_user_review($review_content, $data_rating, $shop_id, $user_avatar);
}   
?>


Function code:

        function add_user_review($review,$data_rating,$shop_id,$user_avatar){
        global $wpdb;

        $current_user=wp_get_current_user();
        $current_user_id=$current_user->ID;
        $username=$current_user->display_name;
        $user_email=$current_user->user_email;
        $review_date= date("m/d/Y");
        $in=$wpdb->insert("wp_user_reviews" ,array(
            "review_content"=>$review,
            "review_rating"=>$data_rating,
            "wp_user_id"=>$current_user_id,
            "user_name"=>$username,
            "product_id"=>$shop_id,
            "review_date"=>$review_date,
            "user_email"=>$user_email,
            "user_avatar"=>$user_avatar,        
    ));

    }
```

please help.Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Change your if condition to this

```
if (isset($_POST['review_submit'])) {
    $review_content = $_POST['message_review'];
    $data_rating = $_POST['data-rating'];
    $shop_id = get_the_ID();
    if(add_user_review($review_content, $data_rating, $shop_id, $user_avatar)){
      echo "<script>alert('success')</script>";
    } else {
      echo "<script>alert('fail to insert')</script>";
    }
}
```

> or you can write this in functions.php aswell

```
<script>
 $( ".review_submit_button" ).click(function() {
  alert( "success" );
});
</script>
```

> This is always work for :)